# What's the right way to divide two Int values to obtain a Float?

Tags: haskell, types, floating-point, integer

I'd like to divide two `Int` values in Haskell and obtain the result as a `Float`.  I tried doing it like this:

```
foo :: Int -> Int -> Float
foo a b = fromRational $ a % b
```

but GHC (version 6.12.1) tells me "Couldn't match expected type 'Integer' against inferred type 'Int'"  regarding the `a` in the expression.

I understand why: the `fromRational` call requires `(%)` to produce a `Ratio Integer`, so the operands need to be of type `Integer` rather than `Int`.  But the values I'm dividing are nowhere near the `Int` range limit, so using an arbitrary-precision bignum type seems like overkill.

What's the right way to do this?  Should I just call `toInteger` on my operands, or is there a better approach (maybe one not involving `(%)` and ratios) that I don't know about?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You have to convert the operands to floats *first* and then divide, otherwise you'll perform an integer division (no decimal places).

Laconic solution (requires `Data.Function`)

```
foo = (/) `on` fromIntegral
```

which is short for

```
foo a b = (fromIntegral a) / (fromIntegral b)
```

with

```
foo :: Int -> Int -> Float
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.  I'd wondered if I could convert to `Float` first, but somehow managed to overlook `fromIntegral` while browsing through the docs for all the functions in the various numeric classes.  (I don't think the other approach would've done integer division losing decimal places as you alluded to, though:  I was making a `Rational` from the integers, which doesn't lose precision.)

Comment: @Wyzard: You were not making a Rational from the integers. You were treating the result of the operator *as* as a Rational, when in fact it was not. Look at the type signature for `fromRational`: the argument is a Rational, while `Ratio Int` and `Ratio Integer` are both different types. You may have intended `toRational`.

Comment: @Chuck: `Rational` is an alias for `Ratio Integer`, and `(%)` returns a `Ratio` of whatever type its operands are, so applying it to two `Integer` should produce a `Rational` (unless I'm misunderstanding).  My problem was that I was giving it `Int` and producing `Ratio Int` (which is indeed *not* a `Rational`).

Comment: @Wyzard: You can convert here using `fromIntegral` again ... It's quite generic.